# in netbeans and php, how can i find out all the files/areas of a program where a certain function/method is called

Tags: php, function, netbeans, methods, call

basically i have this method, where it's being called all over the place in my php program.  Is there a way in netbeans to find out exactly where or how many times that particular method is being called in my php program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install and use xdebug: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug.

Go through this article, it also cover tracing, which may help you understand the execution flow: http://devzone.zend.com/1120/introducing-xdebug/

Comment: It's called tracing. Method and function calls can be generated at runtime, so you cannot reliably detect these calls by only using static code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way but if you refactor that method Netbeans should prompt you to search for all usages and update. In this case you just wouldn't update.